# AngularJS ngClick vs binding to click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is a two part question:

**Part 1**

What's the difference between binding to an event, say `click` using the `ngClick` attribute, vs using the `element.bind('click')`? For instance, I can have

**HTML**

```
<div ng-click="doStuff()">
```

**JS**

```
// Link function of a directive
link: function(scope, element, attrs)
{
    scope.doStuff = function() { // doing stuff //}
}
```

OR, I could ignore the `ng-click` inside my `<div>` and straight forward jump to the directive:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs)
{
    element.bind('click', function() 
    {
        // doing stuff
    });
}
```

**Part 2**

Now, clearly there is a difference in what I can only assume is the `$digest` cycle. I have the following function that runs upon `ng-click` to create a new entry, and this entry is then gets a class added to it:

```
$('.cell').removeClass('selected');

scope.shift.createTask(scope.grid);

scope.schedule.modified();

// Wait until the DOM is digested before finding the last entry
$timeout(function(){
    var elem = element.closest('.shift').find('.task:last-child');
    activateTask(elem);
},0);
```

The above code works fine if I use the `ng-click` method. But when I use the `element.bind('click')` method, the last entry with the `$timeout` doesn't add the class. It always seems to be one behind (i.e. the first `task` added and nothing happens. The second `task` added, and the first task gets the class)

Comment: Essentially, `ngClick` triggers a digest cycle, while `bind` doesn't.

Comment: Part 2 : probably because you are changing the scope from outside angular and when you do that you need to tell angular using `$apply`

Comment: Highly suggested reading: [how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl. I'll definitely read that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the source code for ngClick, it binds to the click event and calls the function within the $apply block:

```
   ngEventDirectives[directiveName] = ['$parse', function($parse) {
       return {
           compile: function($element, attr) {
            var fn = $parse(attr[directiveName]);
               return function ngEventHandler(scope, element) {
             element.on(lowercase(name), function(event) {
             scope.$apply(function() {
                  fn(scope, {$event:event});
             });
        });
      };
    }
  };
}];
```

I suggest that to fix your issue, put more into your $timeout block. It is likely there is some code that needs to be in the same context as the $apply block that $timeout uses :

```
// Wait until the DOM is digested before finding the last entry
$timeout(function(){

    $('.cell').removeClass('selected');

       scope.shift.createTask(scope.grid);

       scope.schedule.modified();

       var elem = element.closest('.shift').find('.task:last-child');

       activateTask(elem);
   },0);
```